# How to do count(*) for specific alias in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL command with multiple tables added with `LEFT JOIN table1 AS alias`. I want to count all rows in `table1`, but not `table2`.

In a command where there's only one table, I can just do `count(*)`. Here, however, `*` refers to all the rows in all the conjoined tables. `table1.*` gets all the rows from just that table, but `count(table1.*)` throws an `Incorrect syntax near '*'.` error.

Is this a syntax problem, or something deeper? How do I get the desired functionality?

Running Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: should be just simply `COUNT ( * )`

Comment: Why don't you count the rows of table1 by a column name like `COUNT(table1.columFromTable1)` ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also present your query.

Comment: You can use outer apply instead of left join and calculate count inside apply expression. Depends on what You should count....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of query like this

```
select *,count(C.CustomerID) over (partition by U.UserID)
from Users U
left join Customers C on C.ManagerID = U.UserID
where U.UserID between  1574 and 1580
```

You can use query like this

```
select *
from Users U
outer apply (
        select Cnt = count(*) from  Customers 
        where ManagerID = U.UserID ) res
where U.UserID between  1574 and 1580
```